# Azure Odata retrieve requirements, their related tests cases and test case outcome in single query

Tags: azure, azure-devops, odata

I am trying to retrieve data using the Odata API from Azure DevOps.

What I want to achieve is to get

- all requirements (CMMI template)
- related test cases
- LastResultOutcome of the test cases.

I have managed to retrieve the outcome, but have got stuck receiving the requirements and tests cases.

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{Orga Name}/{Project Name}/_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItems?$select=AssignedTo,Iteration, WorkItemId, Title, State, Microsoft_VSTS_Common_ReviewedBySK&$apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'Requirement')&$expand=Iteration($select=IterationName), AssignedTo ($select=UserName), Links(                    $select=LinkTypeName;                    $expand=TargetWorkItem($select=WorkItemType,WorkItemId,Title,State, ; $expand = AssignedTo($select=UserName)))
```

can you please help?